# Delete first element of every sublist of a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to delete the first element from every sublist

```
   list[[1:] for i in range(n)]
```

I tried del [0] that did not work either

Comment: `lst[sub_list[1:] for sub_list in lst]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple but effective.

```py
for x in a:
   del x[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple one liner:

```
result = [i[1:] for i in list_input]
```